# Advent Calendar - Use cookies to stop user opening "calendar door" twice

Tags: jquery, cookies

This question may take some explaining so will explain my project:

I working on a Christmas Advent Calendar, from which users can open a link behind hidden behind a door which opens on hover using CSS animations.

The animation will only initiate if element has a class of .activeAdv which in turn is added only when the element contains content. This function is controlled using Wordpress scheduled posts (one for each day of December)

My question is about **how I would go about using cookies to stop a returning user being able to open the same door twice**.

Once they have clicked a link within box a cookie should be set so that the door will automatically open on load and any content within removed.

I have a codepen demo of functionality so far and have also included cookie.js which I have some experience with.

http://codepen.io/Jambob/pen/wKyoRr

Below is a snippet of code for one box:

```
<article>
  <div id="on-1" class="box">
    <h2>1 dec</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="present">
    sample content
    <a href=" www.google.com"> www.google.com</a>
  </div>
</article>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".present").filter(function(){
    return $(this).html().trim().length > 0;
    }).parent().addClass('activeAdv');

});
</script>
```

I do hope this question is clear in the asking, I have knowledge of how to set cookies and also how to detect them, my question is really regarding the logic of approaching this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated and i'm sure Santa would be proud...

Comment: They can still open a different browser (IE, FF, Chrome, Opera etc) that does not contain the cookie.

Comment: It is really for the sake of appearances, if someone was to use a different browser / clear cache they would indeed be able to reopen all previous doors. Could you suggest a different method other than cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to show the link if you have it and don't have a cookie set. Each time the user sees a link then the cookie should be set. The user can see the cookie until the page is navigated away from.

```
$(".present").filter(function(){
    var $present = $(this);
    var $link = $present.find('a');
    var haveLink = $link.length > 0;
    // no link means no op
    if (!haveLink) {
        return false;
    }
    // create a unique name per link
    var cookieName = "link-" + $link.attr('href').trim();
    // see if we have a cookie by that name
    var haveCookie = $.cookie(cookieName);
    // set the cookie because this page load is the last time they can see it
    // if we don't have a cookie we can show the link
    var showLink = !haveCookie;
    // alway set the cookie so we don't show
    $.cookie(cookieName, true);
    return showLink;
 }).parent().addClass('activeAdv');
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8bp8p60/1/)

Comment: var cookieName = "link-" + $link.attr('href').trim(); looks like the key here, I was thinking along these lines, the user would end up with 25 cookies for the 25 days of the calendar correct?

Comment: Yes, you could also do one cookie and store a json object, of all the dates and search for that, or you could give the links unique ids and store those. At any rate you need a way to differentiate the links in your cookie(s).

Comment: I gave this a try on my localhost, does indeed set a cookie of link-http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com but door still opens